# jquery create checked checkbox

Tags: jquery

**How to create checked checkbox element with jquery?**

I have tried with.

```
$('<input>', {
    type:"checkbox",
    "checked":"checked"
});
```

and

```
var input = $('<input>', {
    type:"checkbox"
});
input.attr('checked',true);
```

These are not working.
the checkbox is remain unchecked after appending to element.

Answer (score 10):

***you have to append them to Document.***

For example:

```
$('<input>', {
    type:"checkbox",
    "checked":"checked"
}).appendTo('body'); // instead of body you can use any valid selector
                     // to your target element to which you want to
                     // append this checkbox
```

The code

```
$('<input>', {
    type:"checkbox",
    "checked":"checked"
});
```

Just create an element but not append it to DOM. In order to append it to DOM you have to use ***[`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append)*** / ***[`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo)*** / ***[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html)*** etc any one method.

In case of second snippet:

```
var input = $('<input>', {
    type:"checkbox"
});
input.attr('checked',true);

$('#target_container').append(input);

// Or

input.appendTo('#target_container');
```

Comment: how to draw unchecked check box.